# Unable to get reviewer info with reviews

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

**I'm using this route:**

```
{pageId}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story,reviewer,has_review,has_rating,rating
```

**I'm following this documentation:**

I'm using Graph API Route to get reviews of a page using `{page}/rating`. But there is no reviewer information in the response like name and image.

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings**
How can I get the reviewer information with reviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an open issue related to this problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/185216210374165/?join_id=f26f11c64b760f

Maybe you should subscribe or write a new comment in order to push for an answer.